# "internal server error" while adding web.config file to angular 5 app in IIS

Tags: angular, iis

i have a angular 5 app in IIS. shes work fine excluding the rotning.

i add the "web.config" file as recommended. and this his content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="angular cli routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and now when i running the site, i get this error:

> 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you
>   are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

any idea? thanks a lot!

Comment: There can be multiple. First, the static content part might trigger errors if such extensions are already there at server level, depending on IIS version. Second, URL Rewrite module must be installed on IIS, or the related section should trigger 500.19 errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please check following settings
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".json"/>
        <remove fileExtension=".woff"/>
        <remove fileExtension=".woff2"/>
        <remove fileExtension=".svg"/>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />          
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: this does not fix the issue